# Expanding textview hides image

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

[image]

As shown above, This is my custom listview with some check marks on few of them. Basically there are two textviews and one imageview. My problem is whenever the text in the upper textview is large, the imageview gets out of the screen and the checkmark is not shown.

I want that the width of the upper textview should expand according to the length of the text but it should not hide the check mark.

Any help Appreciate.

EDIT:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="6dip"
android:background="@color/black">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
    android:id="@+id/row_image"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/multiselect_icon"
        android:src="@drawable/singlecheck"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/row_image"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/top_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/multiselect_icon"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>
                    <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/shared_icon"
                            android:src="@drawable/sharedcheck"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/top_view"
                            android:visibility="gone"/>
                    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_view_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
            android:layout_below="@id/top_view"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/multiselect_icon"
                            android:gravity="left"
                            android:textColor="@color/lightGray"
                            android:visibility="gone"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/top_view"
            android:gravity="right"
                            android:textColor="@color/lightGray"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thought sharing the answer so that it might help someone.

I added the upper textbox & the check mark into a linearlayout & it solved the problem.

```
<LinearLayout
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:id="@+id/upper_view"
   android:layout_toRightOf="@id/multiselect_icon"
   android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
   android:layout_alignParentRight="false">

   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/top_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>
   <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/shared_icon"
    android:src="@drawable/sharedcheck"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/top_view"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: But that keeps the sharedcheck image aligned to the right, doesn't it?

Comment: @monchote yes it does. but atleast it is visible now for always. I tried playing with the weights to make it as above but didn't get through. If you can provide anything with that, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

on `textview` in xml .

Comment: I've posted my xml...any help appreciated.

Comment: you can put a check on length of the text for instance if >20 curtail it or append ... watever you prefer

Comment: Or you can put a horizontal scrollview and put textview inside that 
keep layout width fixed

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12800/discussion-between-sunny-kumar-aditya-and-pankaj)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a `LinearLayout` for your ListView items, I would recommend you replace it with a `RelativeLayout` and then make the `TextView` align to the left of the checkmark.

Comment: I'm using relative layout only with the align left thing also. It's not working.